# Error when importing a .ts file into a .js file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have .js files and would like to integrate some .ts files we have. When I try to import them I get some odd errors.

Here is the import in my .js file:

```
import {AuthComponent} from './auth/auth.component';
```

Here is that .ts file (`auth.component.ts`):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from '../user/user.service'; //also a .ts file

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.scss']
})

export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  loadingConfig: any = {
    fullScreenBackdrop: true,
    backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)',
    primaryColour: '#b8860b'
  };
};
```

When I try to compile the app I get the following

`Error in ./app/auth/auth.component.ts
 Module parse failed: /data/1/projects/myapp/src/app/auth/auth.component.ts Unexpected character '@' (7:0)
 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Line 7 is the `@Component`

In my `webpack.config.js` I added:

```
resolve: {
   extensions: ['.ts', '.js','.json']
}
```

I also create a `tsconfig.json` in the root of `app`...that has:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "allowJs": true,
  "checkJs": true
}
```

Im guessing I can import a .ts file into a .js file... but maybe Im missing something?
thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely normal, Javascript does not know what Typescript is. Your error occurs cuz of decorators which aren't implemented in JS yet.

Comment: ok... thanks. so sounds like the solution is to convert them. the .js files to .ts or the .ts files to .js?